# User written command "tpm" generates invalid syntax error in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to run the example provided in the help file of user written command "tpm" (`ssc install tpm`), but it is giving the error `invalid syntax`.

```
webuse womenwk, clear
replace wage = 0 if wage==.
set trace on
tpm wage educ age married children, f(probit) s(regress)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- begin tpm ---
- if _by() {
  local BY `"by `_byvars'`_byrc0':"'
  }
- local _vv: di "version `c(version_rng)', missing:"
= local _vv: di "version , missing:"
- `_vv' `BY' _vce_parserun tpm, jkopts(eclass): `0'
= version , missing:  _vce_parserun tpm, jkopts(eclass): wage educ age married children, f(probit) s(regress)
invalid syntax
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- end tpm ---
r(198);
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace answers your question. The program can't find a setting `c(version_rng)` and is substituting blank. This makes the subsequent call to `version` illegal.

This is probably a combination of two factors:

1. You are using an older version of Stata than the program needs, and the first sign of that happens to be that `c(version_rng)` is not defined in your version. You should tell us what version of Stata you are using.
2. The main program `tpm` lacks a `version` statement. Sometimes this is deliberate, but here it looks like a bug. If #1 is true, normally you don't even get into the program, as the `version` statement throws you out, but here there isn't one.

The best protocol by far with problems like these is (1) to post on Statalist (2) to contact the authors. My recollection is that these authors watch Statalist any way.

There is more on `version` at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/user-written-programs-and-stata-version/

There is more on `creturn` stuff under its help.

Comment: Thanks Nick. The `tpm` version is version 11 (as seen in ado file) and I am also using version 11.

Comment: I can't experiment right now but my conjecture is `tpm`'s `version` statement understates what is required. You should `update` to 11.2, not 11, in any case. Contact the authors too, as it's their bug or misfeature as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will email the authors.